# C warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

Tags: c

so, I have this code:

```
/*
*    CXenon VM v0.0.0
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define IADD 1          // integer add
#define ISUB 2          // integer substract
#define IMUL 3          // integer multiply
#define IDIV 4          // integer divide
#define ILT 5           // integer less than
#define IEQ 6           // integer equals
#define BR 7
#define BRT 8
#define BRF 9
#define ICONST 10       // integer constant
#define LOAD 11         // load from data memory
#define GLOAD 12        // global load from data memory
#define STORE 13        // store in data memory
#define GSTORE 14       // global store in data memory
#define PRINT 15        // print
#define PRINTLN 16      // print with trailing newline
#define POP 17          // pop from stack
#define CALL 18         // call function
#define RET 19
#define FADD 20
#define FSUB 21
#define FMUL 22
#define FDIV 23
#define FCONST 24
#define FLT 25
#define FEQ 26
#define FMT 27
#define FNEQ 28
#define IMT 29
#define INEQ 30
#define BCONST 31
#define BEQ 32
#define BNEQ 33
#define BTRUE 34
#define BFALSE 35
#define HALT 36

char* opcodes[] = {
    "",
    "IADD",
    "ISUB",
    "IMULL",
    "IDIV",
    "ILT",
    "IEQ",
    "BR",
    "BRT",
    "BRF",
    "ICONST",
    "LOAD",
    "GLOAD",
    "STORE",
    "GSTORE",
    "PRINT",
    "PRINTLN",
    "POP",
    "CALL",
    "RET",
    "FADD",
    "FSUB",
    "FMUL",
    "FDIV",
    "FCONST",
    "FLT",
    "FEQ",
    "FMT",
    "FNEQ",
    "IMT",
    "INEQ",
    "BCONST",
    "BEQ",
    "BNEQ",
    "BTRUE",
    "BFALSE",
    "HALT"
};

struct stack_base{
    char* somechars;
    char achar;
    int anint;
    float afloat;
    bool abool;
};

int vm_cpu(struct stack_base* code, bool trace, int datasize){

    struct stack_base stack[100];
    struct stack_base data[datasize];

    int ip = 0; // instructionpointer
    int fp; // framepointer
    int sp = -1; // stackpointer
    int v;
    int addr;
    int nargs;
    int rvalue;
    int a, b;
    float fv;
    float fa, fb;
    bool bv;
    bool ba, bb;

    int opcode = code[ip].anint; // fetch
    int size = sizeof(code); // declares size of code
    //bool trace = false;

    while(ip < size){

        if(trace){
            printf("%04d: %s\n",ip, opcodes[opcode]); // prints trace
        }

        ip++;
        switch(opcode){
            case ICONST:
                v = code[ip].anint;
                ip++;
                sp++;
                stack[sp].anint = v;
                break;
            case ISUB:
                b = stack[sp--].anint;
                a = stack[sp--].anint;
                stack[++sp].anint = a - b;
                break;
            case IADD:
                b = stack[sp--].anint;
                a = stack[sp--].anint;
                stack[++sp].anint = a + b;
                break;
            case IMUL:
                b = stack[sp--].anint;
                a = stack[sp--].anint;
                stack[++sp].anint = a * b;
                break;
            case IDIV:
                b = stack[sp--].anint;
                a = stack[sp--].anint;
                stack[++sp].anint = a/b;
                break;
            case ILT:
                b = stack[sp--].anint;
                a = stack[sp--].anint;
                if(a > b){
                    stack[++sp].abool = true;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    stack[++sp].abool = false;
                    break;
                }
            case IMT:
                b = stack[sp--].anint;
                a = stack[sp--].anint;
                if(a < b){
                    stack[++sp].abool = true;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    stack[++sp].abool = false;
                    break;
                }
            case IEQ:
                b = stack[sp--].anint;
                a = stack[sp--].anint;
                if(a == b){
                    stack[++sp].abool = true;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    stack[++sp].abool = false;
                    break;
                }
            case INEQ:
                b = stack[sp--].anint;
                a = stack[sp--].anint;
                if(a != b){
                    stack[++sp].abool = true;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    stack[++sp].abool = false;
                    break;
                }
            case FCONST:
                fv = code[ip].afloat;
                ip++;
                sp++;
                stack[sp].afloat = fv;
                break;
            case FSUB:
                fb = stack[sp--].afloat;
                fa = stack[sp--].afloat;
                stack[++sp].afloat = fa + fb;
                break;
            case FADD:
                fb = stack[sp--].afloat;
                fa = stack[sp--].afloat;
                stack[++sp].afloat = fa + fb;
                break;
            case FMUL:
                fb = stack[sp--].afloat;
                fa = stack[sp--].afloat;
                stack[++sp].afloat = fa * fb;
                break;
            case FDIV:
                fb = stack[sp--].afloat;
                fa = stack[sp--].afloat;
                stack[++sp].afloat = fa/fb;
                break;
            case FEQ:
                fb = stack[sp--].afloat;
                fa = stack[sp--].afloat;
                if(fa == fb){
                    stack[++sp].abool = true;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    stack[++sp].abool = false;
                    break;
                }
            case FLT:
                fb = stack[sp--].afloat;
                fa = stack[sp--].afloat;
                if(fa > fb){
                    stack[++sp].abool = true;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    stack[++sp].abool = false;
                    break;
                }
            case FMT:
                fb = stack[sp--].afloat;
                fa = stack[sp--].afloat;
                if(fa < fb){
                    stack[++sp].abool = true;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    stack[++sp].abool = false;
                    break;
                }
            case FNEQ:
                fb = stack[sp--].afloat;
                fa = stack[sp--].afloat;
                if(fa != fb){
                    stack[++sp].abool = true;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    stack[++sp].abool = false;
                    break;
                }
            case BCONST:
                bv = code[ip].anint;
                ip++;
                sp++;
                if(bv == BTRUE){
                    stack[sp].abool = true;
                    break;
                }
                else if(bv == BFALSE){
                    stack[sp].abool = false;
                    break;
                }
            case BNEQ:
                bb = stack[sp--].abool;
                ba = stack[sp--].abool;
                if(ba == bb){
                    stack[++sp].abool = true;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    stack[++sp].abool = false;
                    break;
                }
            case BEQ:
                bb = stack[sp--].abool;
                ba = stack[sp--].abool;
                if(ba != bb){
                    stack[++sp].abool = true;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    stack[++sp].abool = false;
                    break;
                }
            case PRINT:
                v = stack[sp].anint;
                sp--;
                printf("%i", v);
                break;
            case PRINTLN:
                //v = stack[sp].anint;
                //fv = stack[sp].afloat;
                bv = stack[sp].abool;
                sp--;
                printf("%d\n", bv);
                break;
            case GLOAD:
                addr = code[ip].anint;
                ip++;
                v = data[addr].anint;
                sp++;
                stack[sp].anint = v;
                break;
            case GSTORE:
                v = stack[sp].anint;
                sp--;
                addr = code[ip].anint;
                ip++;
                data[addr].anint = v;
                break;
            case CALL:
                addr = code[ip++].anint;
                nargs = code[ip++].anint;
                stack[++sp].anint = nargs;
                stack[++sp].anint = fp;
                stack[++sp].anint = ip;
                fp = sp;
                ip = addr;
                break;
            case RET:
                rvalue = stack[sp--].anint;
                sp = fp;
                ip = stack[sp--].anint;
                fp = stack[sp--].anint;
                nargs = stack[sp--].anint;
                sp -= nargs;
                stack[sp++].anint = rvalue;
                break;
            case HALT:
                return 0;
                break;
        }
        opcode = code[ip].anint;
    }

}

void main(){
    struct stack_base hello[] = {
        BCONST, BTRUE,
        BCONST, BTRUE,
        BNEQ,
        PRINTLN,
        HALT
    };
    vm_cpu(hello, true, 4);
}
```

when I compile that code, I get these errors:

```
thewatcher@thewatcher ~/Xenon/CXenon/src $ gcc main.c -o test
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:402:9: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
         BCONST, BTRUE,
         ^
main.c:402:9: warning: (near initialization for ‘hello[0].somechars’) [enabled by default]
main.c:405:9: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
         PRINTLN,
         ^
main.c:405:9: warning: (near initialization for ‘hello[1].somechars’) [enabled by default]
```

I don't understand why this happens and I have no idea how to solve this. Could someone help me?

Comment: There are line numbers in the error message, why don;t you check them?

Comment: `void main()` should be `int main(void)`. `int size = sizeof(code);` is the size of the pointer, not the number of elements.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I did that, but I don't understand how to solve the problem

Comment: @mch changing those things doesn't get rid of any error messages

Comment: I am not familiar with the way you init the struct array. But when you initialise your struct array in the main(). You init it with int values (BCONST etc.). But your first element in the struct is "char* somechars" and not an int.

Comment: What do you expect `struct stack_base hello[] = {
        BCONST, BTRUE,
        BCONST, BTRUE,
        BNEQ,
        PRINTLN,
        HALT
    };` to do?

Comment: No, @mch's changes don't get rid of any error messages. That's why mch posted a comment, not an answer. There are more problems in your code than what the compiler is complaining about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you initialize your structure array `hello` correctly, the errors you are facing should disappear.  The way you initialize it currently is *very* confusing, as the compiler tells you:

> warning: (**near initialization** for ‘hello[0].somechars’) [enabled by default]

Meaning that there is an error with the way you initialize your structure array ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415158/what-is-near-initialization) to fully understand the grammar involved in the error).  Your second error:

> warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast

The compiler is also confused in your initialization of your structure array.  Take, for example, this initialization:

```
struct my_struct {
   int a;
   int b;
}
//Create a structure assigning the value of a to 10 and b to 20:
struct my_struct foo = {10, 20};
```

This will initialize *one* structure, not multiple.  If you wanted to use a similar syntax creating an array of structures, you could do something like this:

```
//Use my_struct from the previous example
struct my_struct foo[] {
   {.a = 10, .b = 20},
   {.a = 1, .b = 2},
   {.a = 5, .b = 5}
};
```

To understand this syntax further, see [designated initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330793/how-to-initialize-a-struct-in-accordance-with-c-programming-language-standards).  The syntax above creates an array of structures with these members for each structure in the array:

```
foo[0].a = 10;
foo[0].b = 20;

foo[1].a = 1;
foo[1].b = 2;

foo[2].a = 5;
foo[2].b = 5;
```

Initialize `struct stack_base hello[]` to have these values for each member:

```
//hello[0].somechars will be assigned the string "hello"
hello[0].achar = 'a';
hello[0].anint = 1;
hello[0].afloat = 1.0;
hello[0].abool = 0;

//hello[1].somechars will be assigned the string "bye bye"
hello[1].achar = 'b';
hello[1].anint = 2;
hello[1].afloat = 10.0;
hello[1].abool = 1;
```

Then, you could write:

```
struct stack_base hello[] {
   {.achar = 'a', .anint = 1, .afloat = 1.0, .abool = 0},
   {.achar = 'b', .anint = 2, .afloat = 10.0, .abool = 1}
};

//Assign strings to achar
strcpy(hello[0].somechars, "hello");
strcpy(hello[1].somechars, "bye bye");
```

In the example above, instead of assigning exact values to each member of the structure, it would make sense for you to replace the assignments to each member with the constants.  For example, you might replace `.anint = 1` with `.anint = BCONST`, etc.

Currently, however, it is simply confusing the way you have initialized your structure array.

Comment: @TheWatcher_...I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

The structure member initialization in your main function is different from you structure definition.
You structure member should be initialized like this.

```
struct stack_base hello[] = {
        {
            "hey there",'a',22,11,true
        },
        {
            "thank you",'b',11,11,false
        },
        {
            "hello",'c',11,11,true
        }
  };
```

And the following line,

> int size = sizeof(code);

`code` is just a pointer to the structure whose size is always 4 (older systems) or 8 (newer systems) bytes. I guess you are trying to find number of members in `hello[]` structure array. In this case either you have to pass this number separately as a function to `vm_cpu` function or use some logic to determine this number within the vm_cpu function.
In case you don't want to pass no. of members as an argument, initialize the structure in `main` fn as follows:

```
struct stack_base hello[] = {
        {
            "abc",'a',11,11,true
        },
        {
            "abc",'a',11,11,true
        },
        {
            "abc",'a',11,11,true
        },NULL
};
```

And in vm_cpu function, use the following logic to find out no. of structure array elements.

```
int size = 0;
    struct stack_base *ptr = code;

    while(ptr[size].somechars) {
        size++;
        ptr++;
    }
    size--;
    printf("The no. of elements of structure array: %d\n", size);
```