# "initializer element is not constant" and "near initialization"

Tags: c, initialization

I want to return an array, and since it doesn't matter if it gets overwritten, my method is this:

```
double * kryds(double linje_1[], double linje_2[]){
double x = linje_1[1]*linje_2[2]-linje_1[2]*linje_2[1];
double y = linje_1[2]*linje_2[0]-linje_1[0]*linje_2[2];
double z = linje_1[0]*linje_2[1]-linje_1[1]*linje_2[0];
static double svar[] = {x, y, z};
return svar;
}
```

However, I get an error at the `static double svar[] = {x, y, z};` . Can someone please explain what it means? I've read other forum posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415158/what-is-near-initialization) but that doesn't really apply to my case

Comment: Your initializer elements are not constant expressions.

Comment: The initializer for a `static` object must be a *constant expression*, meaning something that can be evaluated at compile time (a literal, a macro that expands to a literal, or an expression containing only those elements).  The values of `x`, `y`, and `z` are not established until run time, so they cannot be used as initializers for a `static` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it means what it says

- Initializers must be constant expressions,

but not just that you can't return a local array because it's undefined behavior (*making it `static` solves the problem but causes other problems*), instead try with a `struct`.

```
struct point3d {double x; double y; double z; };
struct point3d kryds(double *linje_1, double *linje_2)
{
    struct point3d result;
    result.x = linje1[1] * linje2[2] - ...
    result.y = ...

    // and so on
    return result;
}
```

Or if you MUST return a `double *`, then try with `malloc()` which is better than `static double svar[]`

```
double *svar;

svar = malloc(3 * sizeof(*svar));
if (svar == NULL) // This will almost NEVER happen, but you MUST check
    return NULL;
svar[0] = linje_1[1] * linje_2[2] - linje_1[2] * linje_2[1];
// And so on
```

you need to remember to `free()` the pointer later on when you *know for sure* that you wont use it anymore.

Or, if you insist

```
static double svar[3];

svar[0] = linje_1[1] * linje_2[2] - linje_1[2] * linje_2[1];
// And so on
```

and you don't need auxiliary `x`, `y` and `z` in any of the proposed solutions in my answer.

Comment: *Or*, pass the target array as an additional parameter to the function.

Comment: Stupid question, but how do I print out the struct? it's obviously not %f

Comment: or `struct point3d kryds(double *linje_1, double *linje_2) {
return (struct point3d ) { linje_1[1] * linje_2[2] - linje_1[2] * linje_2[1],
    ..., ... } ;
  }` with C99/C11.

Comment: @Bassusour The most obvious answer is the answer. One member at a time.